# How to export Plone session configuration?

Tags: session, cookies, plone, zope

I'd like to export my Plone session configuration to my portal product.

The session configuration is set via the ZMI -> acl-users -> session -> properties

I have tried creating a snapshot of the site but can't locate the session configuration within the snapshot xml...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, there is no GenericSetup configuration support included in `plone.session`; there is currently nothing that'll export it for you, nor anything to then import the settings.

You'd have to write a setup step for it instead, and configure the session plugin manually through that.

Add an import step to your `configure.zcml` configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:genericsetup="http://namespaces.zope.org/genericsetup"

<genericsetup:importStep
    name="yourpackage.a_unique_id_for_your_step"
    title="Configures the plone.session plugin"
    description="Perhaps an optional description"
    handler="your.package.setuphandlers.setupPloneSession"
    />

</configure>
```

and add an empty 'sentinel' text file to the same profile directory named `youpackage.setup-plonesession.txt`

then add a `setuphandlers.py` module to your package (what `handler` points to in the above example):

```py
def setupPloneSession(context):
    if context.readDataFile('youpackage.setup-plonesession.txt') is None:
        return

    portal = context.getSite()
    plugin = portal.acl_users.session

    # Configure the plugin manually
    plugin.path = '/'
    plugin.cookie_name = '__ac'
    plugin.cookie_domain = ''

    # Set up a shared auth_tkt secret
    plugin._shared_secret = 'YourSharedSecretKey'
    plugin.mod_auth_tkt = True
```

Note that we first test if the sentinel file is present; if you reuse your package setup elsewhere the setup step could be run multiple times if you don't do this.

You'll need to refer to the [plugin source](https://github.com/plone/plone.session/blob/master/plone/session/plugins/session.py) to get an idea of what you can configure, I'm afraid.

Comment: You should never use import_steps.xml because it create a persistent import step that will break your site if you remove the addon. You have to use zcml to declare import steps: http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/components/genericsetup.html?highlight=import%20step#custom-installer-code-setuphandlers-py